# Starting point for solving this integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, quantum-mechanics, gaussian-integral

I have to calculate a pretty ugly integral which is given by:
$$
\psi(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{(p-p_0)^2}{4\,\Delta p^2} - \frac{i}{\hbar}(p-p_0)x_0+\frac{i}{\hbar}(px-\frac{p^2}{2m}t)\right)\mathrm{d}p
$$

It's a solution to the Schrodinger equation and $x_0,p_0$ and $\Delta p$ are constants.

I tried to complete the square on this one, but for me it doesn't seem that the integral gets easier by that. I would be really grateful if someone could give me a good starting point in solving this integral. Maybe completing the square is a good way to do it, if this the case, I will try to do it again with that method.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

The exponent is a quadratic polynomial with some complex coefficients, so the integrand has the form

$$e^{ap^2+2bp+c}$$ where $a$ is real and negative.

You can get rid of $a$ by a scaling of the variable, and of the real part of $b$ by shifting the variable. The constant coefficient can be factored away. You end-up with an integral for the form

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-p^2}(\cos\omega p+i\sin\omega p)\,dp$$ which is a classical one. (The imaginary part vanishes.)

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E%28-p%5E2%29+cos%28omega+p%29+from+-+inifinity+to+infinity

Comment: First of all thanks for taking the time to answer! I tried this approach, but when I factor out $p^2$ I get  for the constant $a=\frac{1}{4\Delta p^2} + i\frac{t}{\hbar 2m}$ which is not real. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, $a$ is indeed complex. Now we have a Fresnel-like factor, which is embarrassing. Did you try the integral on Wolfram Alpha ? (answer in terms of complex error function)

Comment: From you suggestion to write the exponent in the form of $ap^2+2bp+c$ I tried to complete the square and got to $$exp(-(a(p-\frac{b}{a})^2-\frac{b^2}{a}+c))$$ With the substituion $u=p-\frac{b}{a}$ I get the integral: $$exp(\frac{b^2}{a}-c) \int exp(-au^2) du$$ which should be equal to (atleast I think so) to: $$exp(\frac{b^2}{a}-c) \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$$ (Integrating from $-\infty$ to $\infty$). I think this should give me $\psi(x,t)$ (if my calculations are right). Now I have to find a way to calculate and write out nicely $\left|\psi(x,t)\right|^2$, but that is another story...